# SFDX how to get custom URL as metadata?

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata

I have defined Custom URL as described in documentation
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_url_add.htm&type=5

When I use that command my site metadata doesn't contains this kind of information.

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Site
```

How to get this setting by the `SFDX` command?

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve your Custom URL metadata you should use `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomSite`. Be sure to check which version you're running as there was a previous [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1448) with this command, fixed on CLI 7.146.1.

**Edit as per your last comment:**

What you want is not possible, as the [DomainSite](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_domainsite.htm)'s are records and not retrieveable metadata.

You can still access them by querying the object (`SELECT Id, Domain.Domain, Site.Name FROM DomainSite`).

Best regards!

Comment: when I retrieve `CustomSite` metadata I don't have any information about custom URLs mapping in file `*.site-meta.xml`. Do you have any example of a file that contains custom URLs?

Comment: Hey @hsd! Unfortunately, what you want won't be possible (updated my original answer with more detail regarding that).